# Issues with adding items to an animated CSS3 banner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Attempting to add up to 10 text

items to the animated CSS3 banner. Having issues getting the items to show. Wondered if there is an easier way to do something like this with animations shown in: http://jsfiddle.net/zp6B8/1/

```
<div class="marquee">
    <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Advertisement 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Advertisement 2</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Advertisement 3</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Adrift I'm on Chrome 34.0. Wait for the banner to change, Advertisement 3 overlaps onto Advertisement 2 text.

Comment: Take it no one can help?!

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with putting behavior in CSS. Because the language has no computational abstractions (like a simple for loop), you are going to have to update all that css to hard code in the number of slides.

That said there are a few ways you could make that less painful:

1. You could use a css pre-processor language like stylus that gives you a more terse syntax (no vendor prefixes), as well as some basic abstractions. However you still have to leave the number of slides hard coded even if the preprocessor is generating most the css for you.
2. You could dynamically generate the css from javascript. For example you could write javascript that counts the number of slides and generate css3 animation code and then appends that to the `<head>` of your page.
3. You could not use css3 animation directly, but use it entirely from javascript. For example, you might set all your slides to have a transition time, and then use javascript for moving those slides around.
4. You could just use javascript animations, either jQuery, tween.js or gsap.
5. You could give up entirely and just use a pre-existing javascript slide show.